# Don't know how to trigger map resize to correctly center

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Here's my code, perfectly working except the maps are not correctly centered compared to the markers. From my research, it could be due to the unknown size of the container.
Well, searching about the problem of aligning the map and the marker, I have read that I should use a trigger event to resize my maps (`google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');`). But I tried everything to get this code working and it's not.
Any help appreciated.

```
var coords = [
{lat: 45.731267, lng: 4.827466, zoom: 15},
{lat: 43.648456, lng: 5.252421, zoom: 15},
{lat: 42.393203, lng: -71.151112, zoom: 15}
];
var markers = [];
var maps = [];

function myMaps() {
  for(var i = 0, length = coords.length; i < length; i++)
  {
    var point = coords[i];
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat, point.lng);

    maps[i] = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map' + (i + 1)),
    {
        zoom: point.zoom,
        center: latlng,
        disableDefaultUI: true
    });

    markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: maps[i]
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: The code to use is `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');` but how ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `<center> Your map </center>` in you html where you put your map. It will automatically make your map move to center in any size of container. Hope this will help you.

Comment: It's not the map object which is not centered... it's the map behind the marker which is not correctly centered. It's not related to the html.

Comment: I'm using about the same code as in your question but the "zoom: point.zoom" part i used it with a number such as "zoom: 16" and I'm not using this (disableDefaultUI: true) in my code. It usually will be in the center. Sorry if it didn't help you much.

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work at all. The marker is centered in the element but the map is always slightly offset.